# Is it safe to delete a pull request? Is it better to add a new one?

Tags: github

I have a **develop** branch. I created a branch "add button" for the new task. I made a button on this branch, made `git commit` and `git push` it to github, then made a **pull request** on github for code review and then made a checkout to **develop** in the terminal. But I remembered that I didn’t export the configuration, and the configuration was not added to the indexing(`git add`), `git commit` was not done, accordingly, it is not in the **pull request** on the github.

I thought what could be done in this situation:

1. Delete the Pull request on github or close it if it is not possible to delete it.
2. Add configurations to indexing(`git add`), `git commit`, `git push`.
3. Make a new **pull request**.

Will the new pull request contain the code responsible for creating the button if the branch has already been pushed to github? Or will there be only configuration code and then you should not delete the old pull request?

In this situation, would it be better to create a new commit on the **add button** branch and make another pull request?

Comment: Pull requests have nothing to do with git, so they can be deleted without affecting any git  repos. Recreating PRs with updated commits is fine, but you probably could just push the new commits and github should show them in the PR.

Comment: You need to switch to add button branch, make new commits to it and push it. It will update the pull request.

Comment: The Github PR *will track a branch*, so I suspect the commit was not added to the correct/same branch for the PR. If the code is in a different branch then a different PR must be created to track the different branch. Once a new PR is created for the correct/new branch, the old PR probably serves little purpose. Or, if the commits should be on the branch in the original PR, move it there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't touch the pull request that you've already made. If you push your configuration file in the "add button" branch, then the pull request you made will update automatically to also include this latest commit.

Answer (score 0):

From github documentation https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests

> Once a pull request is opened, you can discuss and review the potential changes with collaborators ××and add follow-up commits before your changes are merged into the base branch××